# WCF call hangs on WCE device when WLAN does not have valid IP

Tags: c#, wcf, compact-framework, windows-ce

I have some Pocket PC 4.2 Devices that communicate with a server wirelessly using WiFi via WCF.  All works well until the wireless network is unable to connect to an AP and obtain a DHCP address (IP on the adapter is 0.0.0.0).  At this point any WCF calls to the server will never return.  If I assign a static IP to the wireless interface, this issue does not occur.

Below is the relevant code, generated by NetCFSvcUtil.exe.  The call to Request() will never return.  If the network adapter has a valid IP and the server is down, the connection will timeout with an exception as expected.  I have tried adding a timeout parameter to the Request() call to no avail.

I can set the devices with static IPs or detect if the IP is invalid before attempting the WCF call, but I would like a better solution if possible, thanks!

```
private System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message getReply(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message msg)
    {
        if ((this.RequestChannelFactory == null))
        {
            // transport doesn't support requests
            throw new System.NotSupportedException();
        }
        System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestChannel requestChannel;
        System.Threading.Monitor.Enter(this.RequestChannelFactory);
        try
        {
            requestChannel = this.RequestChannelFactory.CreateChannel(this.remoteAddress);
        }
        finally
        {
            System.Threading.Monitor.Exit(this.RequestChannelFactory);
        }
        requestChannel.Open();
        try
        {
            return requestChannel.Request(msg);
        }
        finally
        {
            if ((requestChannel.State == System.ServiceModel.CommunicationState.Opened))
            {
                requestChannel.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```